# echo value from DB as a Link in PHP/HTML table

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have a php file with a connection to my DB. In the DB I have a table called sites and a column called url.

I want to echo the value of 'url' as a Link into my table

**DB**

```
$sql = "SELECT url FROM sites";
```

**php**

```
<td>".$row["url"]."</td>
```

I thought something like this but no luck. any pointers please?

```
<td><a href'$url'>".$row["url"]."</td></a>
```

Comment: share the full code

Comment: _"I thought something like this but no luck"_ - What does that mean? What _actually_ happens? What does the generated html look like (right click on page, view source)? Where is the `$url` variable populated? It also looks like you're echoing it using PHP? Please don't just post a line here and there, or parts of a line. We need to see the context. Post _all_ relevant code.

Comment: sorry yes, echoing using php thats all, nothing else is needed in regards to context.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must use echo for print value like:

```
echo "<td><a href='".$row['url']."'>".$row['url']."</a></td>";
```

or

```
<td><a href='<?php echo $row['url']; ?>'><?php echo $row['url']; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: did you notice that the HTML is not valid, the <a> and <td> are not nested properly.

Comment: Now yes stop downvote random please, the real problem was "how do echo"